# Regular expression to match links containing "Google"

Tags: regex

I want to use PHP regular expressions to match out all the links which contain the word `google`. I've tried this:

```
$url = "http://www.google.com";
$html = file_get_contents($url); 
preg_match_all('/<a.*(.*?)".*>(.*google.*?)<\/a>/i',$html,$links);
echo '<pre />';
print_r($links); // it should return 2 links 'About Google' & 'Go to Google English'
```

However it returns nothing. Why?

Comment: The "problem" here is that you are using Regex when there perfectly good parsers and XPath available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a [dom parser](http://php.net/book.dom), because using regex for html documents can be "painfully" error prone.
Try something like this

```
//Disable displaying errors
libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE);

$url="http://www.google.com";
$html=file_get_contents($url); 


$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$n=0;
foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('a') as $a) {
    //check if anchor contains the word 'google' and print it out
    if ($a->hasAttribute('href')  && strpos($a->getAttribute('href'),'google') ) {
        echo "Anchor" . ++$n . ': '. $a->getAttribute('href') . '<br>';
    }
}
```

Comment: wahoo~~  dom could do this. Thanks a lot. I learn some new one.

Comment: This is different from that the OP wants (at least by looking at his code). It seems he wants to get links where the *text* contains Google, not the URL. But as this is the accepted answer... either he didn't specify it correctly or does not care.

Answer (score 4):

Better is to use [XPath](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) here:

```
$url="http://www.google.com";
$html=file_get_contents($url);

$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$query = "//a[contains(translate(text(), 'GOOGLE', 'google'), 'google')]";
// or just:
// $query = "//a[contains(text(),'Google')]";
$links = $xpath->query($query);
```

`$links` will be a [`DOMNodeList`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php) you can iterate.